# Python: Elegant way of dual/multiple iteration over the same list

Tags: python, iterator

I've written a bit of code like the following to compare items with other items further on in a list.  Is there a more elegant pattern for this sort of dual iteration?

```
jump_item_iter = (j for j in items if some_cond)
try:
    jump_item = jump_item_iter.next()
except StopIteration:
    return
for item in items:
    if jump_item is item:
        try:
            jump_item = jump_iter.next()
        except StopIteration:
            return
    # do lots of stuff with item and jump_item
```

I don't think the "`except StopIteration`" is very elegant

Edit:

To hopefully make it clearer, I want to visit each item in a list and pair it with the next item further on in the list (jump_item) which satisfies some_cond.

Comment: Instead of (or in addition to) code, provide your input/output you are expecting please.

Comment: Is that correct to say that if items = range(10) and some_cond=lambda x: x %2, then
the output should be:
[(0, 1), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 5), (4, 5), (5, 7), (6, 7), (7, 9), (8, 9)]

Comment: Yes, odwl, that would be expected output.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can see any of the existing solutions work on a general one shot, possiboly infinite iter**ator**, all of them seem to require an iter**able**.

Heres a solution to that.

```
def batch_by(condition, seq):
    it = iter(seq)
    batch = [it.next()]
    for jump_item in it:
        if condition(jump_item):
            for item in batch:
                yield item, jump_item
            batch = []
        batch.append(jump_item)
```

This will easily work on infinite iterators:

```
from itertools import count, islice
is_prime = lambda n: n == 2 or all(n % div for div in xrange(2,n))
print list(islice(batch_by(is_prime, count()), 100))
```

This will print first 100 integers with the prime number that follows them.

Comment: Looks like a very good solution. But the batch is not an iterator.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what `compare()` is doing, but 80% of the time, you can do this with a trivial dictionary or pair of dictionaries.  Jumping around in a list is a kind of linear search. Linear Search -- to the extent possible -- should always be replaced with either a direct reference (i.e., a dict) or a tree search (using the bisect module).

Comment: I've removed the reference to compare() as it was confusing - I'm actually doing lots of stuff with item and jump_item - compare was a placeholder. This is Linear Search as `items` is definitely a sequence.

Answer (score 1):

```
paired_values = []
for elmt in reversed(items):
    if <condition>:
        current_val = elmt
    try:
        paired_values.append(current_val)
    except NameError:  # for the last elements of items that don't pass the condition
        pass
paired_values.reverse()

for (item, jump_item) in zip(items, paired_values):  # zip() truncates to len(paired_values)
    # do lots of stuff
```

If the first element of items matches, then it is used as a jump_item.  This is the only difference with your original code (and you might want this behavior).

Answer (score 1):

The following iterator is time and memory-efficient:

```
def jump_items(items):
    number_to_be_returned = 0
    for elmt in items:
        if <condition(elmt)>:
            for i in range(number_to_be_returned):
                yield elmt
            number_to_be_returned = 1
        else:
            number_to_be_returned += 1

for (item, jump_item) in zip(items, jump_items(items)):
    # do lots of stuff
```

Note that you may actually want to set the first number_to_be_returned to 1...

Answer (score 1):

Write a generator function:

```
def myIterator(someValue):
    yield (someValue[0], someValue[1])

for element1, element2 in myIterator(array):
     # do something with those elements.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you're trying to do with that code. But I'm 99% certain that whatever it is could probably be done in 2 lines. I also get the feeling that the '==' operator should be an 'is' operator, otherwise what is the compare() function doing? And what happens if the item returned from the second jump_iter.next call also equals 'item'? It seems like the algorithm would do the wrong thing since you'll compare the second and not the first.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the '==' to be an 'is', that is more correct.
The compare function is a placeholder for a big block of code that doesn't have much relevance to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the whole iteration into a single try structure, that way it would be clearer:

```
jump_item_iter = (j for j in items if some_cond)
try:
    jump_item = jump_item_iter.next()
    for item in items:
        if jump_item is item:
            jump_item = jump_iter.next()

    # do lots of stuff with item and jump_item

 except StopIteration:
     pass
```

Comment: I suppose I could better put the question:
  I want to visit each item in a list and pair it with the next item further on in the list which meets a certain condition.
I'll update the question

Answer (score 0):

So you want to compare pairs of items in the same list, the second item of the pair having to meet some condition. Normally, when you want to compare pairs in a list use `zip` (or `itertools.izip`):

```
for item1, item2 in zip(items, items[1:]):
    compare(item1, item2)
```

Figure out how to fit your `some_cond` in this :)

Comment: I'm not comparing items[i] to items[i+1], so long as `some_cond` is false, item2 can skip ahead multiple places in the list.

Comment: That's why I was talking about figuring out how to fit `some_cond`. something like `others = [item for item in items[1:] if some_cond]` and then `zip(items, others)`.

Comment: Isn't the part that he should "figure out" the actual hard part? And why is your approach the right one for this?

Comment: Hi Virgil - if I zip(items, others) then each item2 will be paired with only one item1; in my current implementation it is possible to pair multiple item1s with the same item2 (until item1 reaches item2 at which point item2 jumps ahead again)

Answer (score 0):

Are you basically trying to compare every item in the iterator with every other item in the original list?

To my mind this should just be a case of using two loops, rather than trying to fit it into one.

```
filtered_items = (j for j in items if some_cond)
for filtered in filtered_items:
    for item in items:
        if filtered != item:
            compare(filtered, item)
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid nested loops as I only need to visit each 'item' once.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simple solution that might look a little cleaner:

```
for i, item in enumerate(items):
    for next_item in items[i+1:]:
        if some_cond(next_item):
            break
    # do some stuff with both items
```

The disadvantage is that you check the condition for next_item multiple times. But you can easily optimize this:

```
cond_items = [item if some_cond(item) else None for item in items]
for i, item in enumerate(items):
    for next_item in cond_items[i+1:]:
        if next_item is not None:
            break
    # do some stuff with both items
```

However, both solutions carry more overhead than the original solution from the question. And when you start using counters to work around this then I think it is better to use the iterator interface directly (as in the original solution).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the main `for item in items:` to "chase" after an iterator that filters out some items. Well, there's not much you can do, except maybe wrap this into a `chase_iterator(iterable, some_cond)` generator, which would make your main code a little more readable.

Maybe that a more readable approach would be an "accumulator approach" (if the order of the compare() don't matter), like:

```
others = []
for item in items:
    if some_cond(item):
        for other in others:
            compare(item, other)
        others = []
    else:
        others.append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range( 0, len( items ) ):
    for j in range( i+1, len( items ) ):
        if some_cond:
            #do something
            #items[i] = item, items[j] = jump_item
```

Answer (score 0):

With just iterators

```
def(lst, some_cond):
      jump_item_iter = (j for j in lst if som_cond(j))
      pairs = itertools.izip(lst, lst[1:])
      for last in jump_item_iter:
        for start, start_next in itertools.takewhile(lambda pair: pair[0] < last, pairs):
          yield start, last
        pairs = itertools.chain([(start_next, 'dummy')], pairs)
```

with the input: range(10) and some_cond = lambda x : x % 2
gives [(0, 1), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 5), (4, 5), (5, 7), (6, 7), (7, 9), (8, 9)]
(same that your example)

Comment: Here, even the 'batch' (see Ants Aasma solution) is an iterable.

Answer (score 0):

Even better using itertools.groupby:

```
def h(lst, cond):
  remain = lst
  for last in (l for l in lst if cond(l)):
    group = itertools.groupby(remain, key=lambda x: x < last)
    for start in group.next()[1]:
      yield start, last
    remain = list(group.next()[1])
```

Usage:
lst = range(10)
cond = lambda x: x%2
print list(h(lst, cond))

will print

```
[(0, 1), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 5), (4, 5), (5, 7), (6, 7), (7, 9), (8, 9)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [j for j in items if some_cond]
for item, jump_item in zip(l, l[1:]):
    # do lots of stuff with item and jump_item
```

If l = [j for j in range(10) if j%2 ==0] then the iteration is over: [(0, 2),(2, 4),(4, 6),(6, 8)].

Comment: it never is too late, but it's not what OP wants

Comment: With items = range(10) and some_cond=lambda x %2,
This will give (1 3), (3 5), (5,7), (7,9)
I think that it is not the question you are missing 0,1 for instance

Comment: how so? the first line gets all the items that satisfy some_cond and the loop is over pairs of such items. ie each element that satisfies cond is paired with the next element that satisfies cond.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your loop body as:

```
import itertools, functools, operator

for item in items:
    jump_item_iter = itertools.dropwhile(functools.partial(operator.is_, item), 
                                         jump_item_iter)

    # do something with item and jump_item_iter
```

dropwhile will return an iterator that skips over all those which match the condition (here "`is item`").

Comment: Are you missing the line `jump_item_iter = items` before the loop body?

Comment: It should be the same as in the question before the loop body. ie jump_item_iter = "(j for j in items if some_cond)"

Comment: I think this doesn't work as there is no way to know when to call jump_item_iter.next() and when to reuse the previous value of jump_item_iter.next()

Comment: jump_item_iter will be replaced with an iterator which will wrap the previous one - calling next() should have the same effect as having applied the check in your loop, return the next item, skipping over an identical one.  However, I might be misinterpreting your code - I've just reread it an noticed that you're using jump_iter in the loop body, which I read as jump_item_iter.  If this is indeed something different, then I think I've misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
import itertools

def matcher(iterable, compare):
    iterator= iter(iterable)
    while True:
        try: item= iterator.next()
        except StopIteration: break
        iterator, iterator2= itertools.tee(iterator)
        for item2 in iterator2:
            if compare(item, item2):
                yield item, item2
```

but it's quite elaborate (and actually not very efficient), and it would be simpler if you just did a

```
items= list(iterable)
```

and then just write two loops over `items`.

Obviously, this won't work with infinite iterables, but your specification can only work on finite iterables.